# How to wrap some elements form the same parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got this kind of markup:

```html
<div id = "main-region">
  <div id = "section-1">
    <p>
      <span id = "index-1">elementA</span>
      <span id = "index-2">elementB</span>
      <span id = "index-3">elementC</span>
      <span id = "index-4">elementD</span>
      <span id = "index-5">elementE</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id = "section-2">
    <p>
      <span id = "index-6">elementF</span>
      <span id = "index-7">elementG</span>
      <span id = "index-8">elementH</span>
      <span id = "index-9">elementI</span>
      <span id = "index-10">elementJ</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id = "section-3">
    <p>
      <span id = "index-11">elementK</span>
      <span id = "index-12">elementL</span>
      <span id = "index-13">elementM</span>
      <span id = "index-14">elementN</span>
      <span id = "index-15">elementO</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to develop a function that, passing to numbers corresponding to index, wrap all span between those index in a span. Say we pass numbers 3 and 12 to that function we want to obtain:

```html
<div id = "main-region">
  <div id = "section-1">
    <p>
      <span id = "index-1">elementA</span>
      <span id = "index-2">elementB</span>
      <span class = "wrapped">
        <span id = "index-3">elementC</span>
        <span id = "index-4">elementD</span>
        <span id = "index-5">elementE</span>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id = "section-2">
    <p>
      <span class = "wrapped">
        <span id = "index-6">elementF</span>
        <span id = "index-7">elementG</span>
        <span id = "index-8">elementH</span>
        <span id = "index-9">elementI</span>
        <span id = "index-10">elementJ</span>
      </span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id = "section-3">
    <p>
      <span class = "wrapped">
        <span id = "index-11">elementK</span>
        <span id = "index-12">elementL</span>
        <span id = "index-13">elementM</span>
      </span>
      <span id = "index-14">elementN</span>
      <span id = "index-15">elementO</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although my javascript and jquery background is low, I've have tried to solved this problem before ask here, and the best approach after several attempts was wrap all the partent's childs not some of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a collection of all the spans that can be used to [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) instances .

Then iterate each parent container and use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) on it's children to build the groups to wrap using [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

```js
function wrapSpans(start, end) {
  var $cont = $('.span-container'),
     //collection of all spans
    $spans = $cont.children();
  // loop all the containers and filter children to wrap
  $cont.each(function() {
    $(this).children('span').filter(function() {
      var idx = $spans.index(this); // index within all spans collection     
      return idx >= (start - 1) && idx <= end;
    }).wrapAll('<span class="wrapped">');
  });
}

wrapSpans(3, 12)
```

```css
span {
  display: block
}

.wrapped {
  border: 1px solid green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-region">
  <div id="section-1">
    <p class="span-container">
      <span id="index-1">elementA</span>
      <span id="index-2">elementB</span>
      <span id="index-3">elementC</span>
      <span id="index-4">elementD</span>
      <span id="index-5">elementE</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="section-2">
    <p class="span-container">
      <span id="index-6">elementF</span>
      <span id="index-7">elementG</span>
      <span id="index-8">elementH</span>
      <span id="index-9">elementI</span>
      <span id="index-10">elementJ</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="section-3">
    <p class="span-container">
      <span id="index-11">elementK</span>
      <span id="index-12">elementL</span>
      <span id="index-13">elementM</span>
      <span id="index-14">elementN</span>
      <span id="index-15">elementO</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one, but wrapSpans(3, 12) covered 4-14, should use `var idx = $spans.index(this) + 1;`

Comment: @DanielH simple modification of the filter conditional is all that is needed

Answer (score 0):

Use attr selector to get all section for each, first you need to remove wrapped tag if previously wrapped or function called.

```
thisSection.find('.wrapped').contents().unwrap();
```

then find all span inside this section, use each to check each single span.

`var thisId = parseInt(value.id.replace('index-', ''));` get the int id of this span

If `thisId` == start? Wrap this span. Or if `thisId` is in between start and and, wrap it to because this is the start of the section (index == 0)

For the rest of span, check if it is bewteen start/end or equal to end, move this div inside the `.wrapped` span using appendTo. `prev()` will find the prev element.

```
$(this).appendTo($(this).prev('.wrapped'));
```

```js
function wrapper(start, end) {
  $('[id^=section]').each(function(index) {
    var thisSection = $(this);
    //remove wrapped tag if previously wrapped
    thisSection.find('.wrapped').contents().unwrap();

    thisSection.find('span').each(function(index, value) {
      var thisId = parseInt(value.id.replace('index-', ''));
      //if start index between start/end OR start == thisId [do wrap]
      if ((index == 0 && start < thisId && thisId <= end) ||
        start == thisId) {
        $(this).wrap('<span class="wrapped"></span>');
      } else if (start < thisId && thisId <= end) {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('.wrapped'));
      }
    })
  })
}

$('#start, #end').on('change', function() {
  wrapper($('#start').val(), $('#end').val())
})

wrapper(3, 12);
```

```css
.wrapped {
  background: red;
}

span {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="start" value="3" />
<input id="end" value="12" />

<div id="main-region">
  <div id="section-1">
    <p>
      <span id="index-1">elementA</span>
      <span id="index-2">elementB</span>
      <span id="index-3">elementC</span>
      <span id="index-4">elementD</span>
      <span id="index-5">elementE</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="section-2">
    <p>
      <span id="index-6">elementF</span>
      <span id="index-7">elementG</span>
      <span id="index-8">elementH</span>
      <span id="index-9">elementI</span>
      <span id="index-10">elementJ</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="section-3">
    <p>
      <span id="index-11">elementK</span>
      <span id="index-12">elementL</span>
      <span id="index-13">elementM</span>
      <span id="index-14">elementN</span>
      <span id="index-15">elementO</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about if the elements I want to wrap are not in order? like 1,4,8,13 only?

Comment: @quirimmo he asked for `wrap all span between those index`

Comment: -.- yep just read it now. thanks. I provided a way for wrapping them with random indexes too.  :D